# The argument type 'void Function(String)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(dynamic)'

Tags: dart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJRCX.png)

Please help me with this.

Comment: this question is terribly formatted check (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), never put code in images it's just bad practice.  post ur code as text, and explain what u are exactly looking to do and what's happening. Also attached what other solutions u've already tried. This is the base u can do for more info read the link.

Answer (score 1):

You should specify that people is a list of string `List<String> people = ...` or you can use `var` and the type will be inferenced `var people = ...`